# Finding the most common set of values

Tags: math, statistics

Given an X amount of sets each containing Y values, how do I find the most common set using?
(Unsure if common is the right word)

As an example I have 6 sets each containing 5 values:

```
A B C D E 
A A D L G 
G A B D F 
A A I F G
A A D F G 
A B E F G
```

How would I go about finding the set that relates to the others the most, being:

```
A A D F G
```

Does this sort of statistics have a name?

Comment: What is you similarity criteria?

Comment: I want to retrieve the set which is most similar to the other sets. Is that what you mean by similarity criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each set, compute the summation of the Levenshtein distance between itself and the other sets.
The set with the smallest summation is the set which is most similar to the others. You can choose to use dynamic programming to improve the efficiency of your program.

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction and something I'll use for the next step, which would then be finding sets that are least like the most common set.

Comment: that's just the set with the largest summation.

Comment: How would you ignore the order of sequences in Levenshtein distance?

Comment: sort the values first then compute the distance